# How can I make a column (Multiple lines of text) read-only?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I'm working with Sharepoint List - No Power Automate, and I'm trying to make columns read-only.

I could make other columns (single line of text) read-only by making a second column of calculated type and making a reference to it.

However, when I tried to make a column (multi line of text), I couldn't do the same as it's not supported by MS.

I looked up the solutions for the whole day but couldn't find any solution.
Some solutions involved using scripts but none of them explained where I could type that code in and just showed the snippet of the code.

Can someone please help me with this situation and provide me a solution or at least a guideline?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where Power Automate would get involved in this scenario at all. If a column is read only, how would the data ever get into the column in the first place, I wonder. I assume that some users will still be able to create entries and enter data in all fields of the list.

If you want to limit editing for parts of the list columns, you may need to involve PowerApps to build a user interface to you specifications.

In the SharePoint list Advanced Settings turn off the ability to edit list items in the details pane and in quick edit.
Then build a PowerApp and present the columns in edit or view mode, as you need.

You can either build a stand-alone PowerApp, so users never actually visit the list istself, or you can customise the SharePoint List form with PowerApps. Using AAD security groups, you can even identify a set of users with elevated permissions and present PowerApps elements differently, depending on the group membership of the current user, so only some users can edit the text fields, but most cannot.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Online, we do not have an out-of-box solution to make a certain list column to be read-only. The calculated column solution is a workaround. If that does not fit your requirements, PowerApps could be an option for you. With it you can do more customization on you list forms.